# Rails - REGEX - validating length of non whitespace / special characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation, activerecord

I have a few fields with a length validation, which can be bypassed by entering n number of white spaces. I'm trying to write a method that validates the number of alpha numeric characters only (not whitespace or special characters).

I've gotten as far as the following:

```
 validates :title,
            presence: true,
            length: { minimum: 4, maximum: 140 },
            format: { with: /([A-z0-9])/ }
```

What I can't get is how to validate the length of the title that matches the format. For example I want to allow a title of 'The Beast', but only count 'TheBeast' in the character count. This will allow 'The Beast' and include the space in the length validation

Is there something built into rails that allows me to do this? Or if not what's the best way go about writing a custom method?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you would have aux column like 'filtered_title' you could do:

```
before_save :filter_title

def filter_title
  self.filtered_title = title.gsub(/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/, '') // strip unneeded chars
end
```

and your validator, but on a the new column

```
 validates :filtered_title,
            presence: true,
            length: { minimum: 4, maximum: 140 },
            format: { with: /([A-z0-9])/ }
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @NeverBe's answer, I went with:

```
class AlphanumericLengthValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    minimum_length = options.fetch(:length, 100)
    stripped_value = value ? value.gsub(/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/, '') : nil
    message = "must be at least #{minimum_length} alphanumeric characters in length"
    return if stripped_value&.length && stripped_value.length >= minimum_length
    record.errors.add(attribute, message) if !stripped_value || stripped_value.length < minimum_length
  end
end
```

Which allowed me to do:

```
  validates :title, alphanumeric_length: { length: 8 }
```